# Multiple Instances of same form with isolated recordsets

Tags: sql, ms-access

http://allenbrowne.com/ser-35.html

The code below is Allen Browne's code to open multiple instances of the same form.  Problem is that I need each forms data to be based on the drop down in 'that' form, not the first.  He has a table as the record source on the form, I have the following SQL embedded in the form.  I think the key is the where statement, or maybe remove the where statement and use filtering.  Right now all forms opened are based on the first forms data.

My SQL Where Statement -

WHERE (((tbl_buyer_column.aels_id)=[forms]![frm_baseline]![ael]))

Allen's Code

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public clnClient As New Collection

Function OpenAClient()
    Dim frm As Form
    Set frm = New Form_frm_baseline
    frm.Visible = True
    frm.Caption = "New Form Opened " & Now()
    clnClient.Add Item:=frm, Key:=CStr(frm.Hwnd)
    Set frm = Nothing
End Function

Function CloseAllClients()
    Dim lngKt As Long
    Dim lngI As Long
    lngKt = clnClient.Count
    For lngI = 1 To lngKt
        clnClient.Remove 1
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. The trick here is to keep track of the forms as you open them too. This is how I do this. You can see when I create the new instance I pass in a parameter that specified the recordset I want to use on that form. You could change it to be a filter just as well.

This is code in a standard module

```
Public multiInstanceDic As Dictionary

'returns the window handle (long)
Public Function OpenNewMyFormSheetInstance(queryForRecordSource As String, Optional inputCaption As String) As Long

    If multiInstanceDic Is Nothing Then
        Set multiInstanceDic = New Dictionary
    End If

    Dim frm As Form
    Set frm = New Form_MyForm
    frm.Caption = inputCaption
    frm.SetRecordSource queryForRecordSource
    multiInstanceDic.Add frm.Hwnd, frm   'required to keep form alive after function exits
    frm.SetFocus

    OpenNewDynamicDataSheetInstance = frm.Hwnd
End Function

Public Function GetMyFormInstance(frmHandle As Long) As Form_MyForm
    Set GetDynamicDataSheetInstance = multiInstanceDic(frmHandle)
End Function
```

I use it like this throughout my app

```
Dim createdWindowHandle As Long
createdWindowHandle = Windows.OpenNewMyFormInstance("VW_SomeView", "A wonderful informative caption")
```

Then whenever I need to change something else about that form that was not handled when I created it I have the `hwnd` handy because I returned it to the caller when the form was created.

```
Dim dMyForm As Form_MySheet
Set dMyForm = Windows.GetMyFormInstance(createdWindowHandle)

dMyForm.[change any public property]
```

This all works pretty well for me. I can have many instances of this same form open at once all with different data. This particular form, when passed a query/recordset, will create bound controls dynamically. But, I don't think you need that. You just need to show two forms with different filters. Totally possible.

Comment: Just curious because I've never done anything like this before, but when do the controls on the new instance of the form become rendered? I figured that perhaps a `Requery` would have been necessary after the form load and while the `Hwnd` was still in focus, however I wasn't sure how the new forms would know what to filter on since they're essentially just making copies of the first form?

Comment: @Brad - Thank you, I found someone that Allen's method as its foundation elsewhere to do something close to what I am trying to do.  That combined with what you have presented I feel confident I can get this done.

Comment: @OverMind the forms's `Open` and `Load` events are fired when you call `New Form_MyForm`. The forms is actually painted on the screen when you call `SetFocus` which has the same effect as `.Visible = true`. A requery would be necessary if you are changing the `where` clause of the recordsource but since OP's just changing the `.Filter` setting `.FilterOn = true` will trigger the filter to be performed.

Comment: @OverMind ...Each new form is a new object so they are totally independent of any other form. Just like when you create `New Dictionary` it creates a new object of the class dictionary but any new object is not related to any old object other than their common structure. Here we have defined a class called `Form_MyForm`. Access just usually let's only one instance be open at a time because it manages this kind of structure on it's own. So DoCmd.OpenForm can only open one form per class.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for responding. In retrospect, is all this necessary? If the OP is making new objects of the *same* form, how will the data returned be any different if the OP is not changing the dropdown on each form to filter the records? Once filtered, I would have thought a `Requery` would have been all that was required. I think I might be having a hard time following, though.

Comment: @OverMind If he wants to use the same kind of form structure and have two open side by side this is the only way to do it. If you are opening one form then doing things, closing it, then opening that form again with different data then yes, this is not necessary.

Comment: My logic: Suppose you have a list of names in a table, and the recordsource for the form is just a `select * from NamesTbl where firstName = forms!People!firstNameTxt` query, and we performed this code. They would all be identical, until something was changed inside `firstNameTxt`. I thought OP's code was to filter all opened instances of the form to match some dropdown on each form? The only thing that would need to be changed, if that is the case, is the change in the dropdown on each form and a requery. Do you see where I'm coming from?

Comment: @OverMind I read it as there are two forms: `F1` and `F2`. They are both instances of the same form. They both, thus, have a combobox. When the combobox on `F1` changes the data on `F1` needs to be filtered. This should not affect `F2`. You would not be able to write your queries like this though `where firstName = forms!People!firstNameTxt` because these forms are not manages by the forms collection. You'll need to either return all records on the form then filter using the `filter` property or use parameterized queries.

Comment: Ah, that last bit summarized my assumptions. I gotcha - thanks for clearing it up for me.