# Missing Data in Multiple instances of a report

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access database that opens multiple instances of 2 reports. The quantity depends on how many student registrations is captured per training run. This may be up to 25, meaning that when the user click on the "Print Documents" button, 25 instances of the 2 reports are opened. The first report is a student registration form, and the second is a indemnity form. Both these forms has certain data on them, like the personal details.

Opening the multiple reports is no issue. The first report is opened with the below code:

```
Z = 1
While Not Rst3.EOF
    Set rpt(Z) = New Report_Rpt_StudentReg
    rpt(Z).Visible = True
    rpt(Z).Caption = "Student Registation " & Rst3.StudentID
    'Append it to the collection.
    clnClient.Add Item:=rpt(Z), Key:=CStr(rpt(Z).hwnd)
    Rst3.MoveNext
    Z = Z + 1
Wend
```

In the report Rpt_StudentReg On Load, there are code running to with SQL statements to retrieve all the data and fill the fields on the report. The second report (Waiver) is opened from within the first report with similar code below:

```
Set rptWaiver(Z) = New Report_Rpt_Indemnity
rptWaiver(Z).Visible = True
rptWaiver(Z).Caption = "Indemnity " & Rst3.StudentID
'Append it to our collection.
clnClient.Add Item:=rptWaiver(Z), Key:=CStr(rptWaiver(Z).hwnd)
```

My issue is none of the data is dispalyed on any of the reports.
If I run a single instance, everything is fine and the relevant data is displayed.

Your assistance is appreciated.

Thanks
Deon

I am opening multiple instances with no issues. In the report's On Load Event, there is code running each time the report is opened. I use SQL to retrieve the data from the tables. Debugging the code, retrieves the correct data, but the data is not on the report when it is opened. The On Load event code as follows:

Private Sub Report_Load()
Set Dbs = CurrentDb: Set Dbs1 = CurrentDb

```
Select Case Mode
    Case "WithData"
        If MyMode = "Certification" Then
            SQL1 = "SELECT StudentID FROM Tbl_Certification WHERE CertNumber = " & Rst3!CertNumber & ";"
            Set Rst1 = Dbs1.OpenRecordset(SQL1)
            SQL = "SELECT * FROM Tbl_StudentReg WHERE IDNumber = " & Rst1!StudentID & ";"
            Set Rst = Dbs.OpenRecordset(SQL)
            Rst1.Close
        Else
            SQL = "SELECT * FROM Tbl_StudentReg WHERE IDNumber = " & Forms!Frm_StudentReg_Edit.IDNumber & ";"
            Set Rst = Dbs.OpenRecordset(SQL)
        End If
        Set Rst = Dbs.OpenRecordset(SQL)
        Me.FirstName = Rst!FirstName
        Surname = Rst!Surname
        PrevSurname = Rst!PrevSurname
        IDNumber = Rst!IDNumber
        BirthDate = Rst!BirthDate
        AltIDNumber = Rst!AltIDNumber
        AltIDType1 = Rst!AltIDType
        '-------------------
        SQL1 = "SELECT * FROM Tbl_AltID WHERE AltID = " & Rst!AltIDType & ";"
        Set Rst1 = Dbs1.OpenRecordset(SQL1)
        AltIDTypeDescr1 = Rst1!AltIDDescr
        '-----------------------------
        Nationality1 = Rst!Nationality
        SQL1 = "SELECT * FROM Tbl_Nationality WHERE NationalityNo = " & Rst!Nationality & ";"
        Set Rst1 = Dbs1.OpenRecordset(SQL1)
        NationalityDescr1 = Rst1!NationalityDescr
        '-------------------------------
```

When the reports are opened for preview, there is no data in the reports. They are all blank.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Instances of same form with isolated recordsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804738/multiple-instances-of-same-form-with-isolated-recordsets). I adapted this code for report and it works. Why are you using the Z increment?

Comment: If reports have personal details data, how do you get each instance to show different record? How do you 'fill the fields on the report'? As far as I can tell, this approach only allows to open multiple copies of report displaying same data. Alternative approach is to open/print/close filtered report before moving to next record. Another is to open multi-record report with page break between students.

Comment: I supposed I really do not have to use the Z increment. It is just for my own use to determine if the code is opening the correct quantity of reports.

Comment: In the Report On Load event, I have some code running to retrieve the data I need for the specific report. Retrieving the data is not the problem. The problem is that the correct data is retrieved and the code assign the data to the correct control on the report. My issue is that the data is not displayed when the report opens. It is blank reports. If the instances of the report opened is 10, all 10 is blank reports. If I run only 1 instance, then all data is displaying on the report.

Comment: Then edit question to provide that code so I can try to replicate circumstances and experience the issue.